# Redux store Not re-rendring the component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

guys, I am working on a react project and I am facing a strange problem my reducer is being called but my state is not changing I checked I am not mutating the state I am returning a new state but still something is wrong and I am not able to identify it please help me. thank in advance.

Here is my bit bucket repo:

https://bitbucket.org/sk_singh_1996/testing_redux.git

Comment: You need to put some relevant code here and not just the bitbucket repo URL

Comment: Also, I don't see you using `provider`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `mapDispatchToProps` to handle actions in your component. for example.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = () => {
   return dispatch => {
      addUser: (input) => dispatch(addUserAction(input))

  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

So in your component you can use `this.props.addUser(val)`